# How to space between rows?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have an expanded widget for my ClipRRect, which I think I need, but I also need to spacebetween my row, but I can't manage it. If I wrap it in an expanded widget it changes the size of my image in ClipRRect, which I don't want to do. This is my code:

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(6),
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: function,

        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[

              Expanded(
                flex: 1,
                child: ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                    child: Stack(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        assetImage,
                      ],
                    ),
                ),
              ),


              Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text('$myText -', style: myTextStyle),
                      SizedBox(width: 5.0,),
                      Text('$locationText', style: myTextStyle),
                    ],
                  ),


                    Card(
                      elevation: 1,
                      color: Colors.white,
                      shape: cardBorder,
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Text('$myText - $endmyText mins', style: myTextStyle,),
                      ),
                    ),
                ],
              ),

            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );

  }
```

Comment: Have you tried a SizedBox between the Expanded and Row widgets?

Comment: Yeah, but it only increases the distance between the image and the row :/

Comment: I didn't understand your problem, you need an space between your Row and what? If it's just to create a space between Expanded and Row, a SizedBox should do it, or you can wrap your Row inside a Padding widget and insert a padding on the top.

Comment: You can set mainAxisAlignment to MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween

Comment: Ah sorry, its between the row with myText and locationPath in it (at the bottom of the code) and the Card. They're both in the same row, but I need them to be spaced equally between each other within the width of the column all my widgets are inside

Comment: Did you tried using padding ?

Comment: Yeah that only reduced the size of everything. I think I'm going to try to put the Row in a container and see if it works. That seems to be the right way of going about this

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your question says you want to divide widgets with equal spaces, for it replaces `Row` with `Wrap` widget

```
       Wrap(
            direction: Axis.horizontal,
            spacing: 30, // add space in between widget
            children: <Widget>[
              Wrap(
                spacing: 30, // add space in between widget
                direction: Axis.horizontal,
```